# \t Doesn't work in my code, neither does \n

Tags: python-2.7

Hey I am wondering why this doesn't work in my code,
I am lead to believe from other forums that putting \t and \n in speech marks should fix the result:

```
zoo = ("Kangaroo","Leopard","Moose")
print("Tuple:", zoo, "\tLength:", len(zoo))
print(type( zoo))

bag = {'Red','Green','Blue'}
bag.add('Yellow')
print('\nSet:',bag,'\tLength' , len(bag))
print(type(bag))

print('\nIs Green In bag Set?:','Green' in bag)
print('Is orange in bag set?:', 'Orange' in bag)

box = {'Red','Purple','Yellow'}
print('\nSet:',box,'\t\tLength' , len(box))
print('Common to both sets:' , bag.intersection(box))
```

It just says:

```
('Tuple:', ('Kangaroo', 'Leopard', 'Moose'), '\tLength:', 3)
<type 'tuple'>
('\nSet:', set(['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red']), '\tLength', 4)
<type 'set'>
('\nIs Green In bag Set?:', True)
('Is orange in bag set?:', False)
('\nSet:', set(['Purple', 'Yellow', 'Red']), '\t\tLength', 3)
('Common to both sets:', set(['Red', 'Yellow']))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a command, not a function, in python2.7, so the parentheses are being interpreted as surrounding tuples, which is what that is what gets printed.  The control characters are being displayed (instead of their effects) because you aren't printing the strings directly, but as part of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it without changing to much is this.

```
zoo = ("Kangaroo","Leopard","Moose")
zlength = len(zoo)
print "Tuple: {}, \tLength: {}".format(zoo,zlength)
print type(zoo)

bag = {'Red','Green','Blue'}
bag.add('Yellow')
blength = len(bag)
print '\nSet: {}, \tLength: {}'.format(list(bag), blength)
print type(bag)

print '\nIs Green In bag Set?:','Green' in bag
print 'Is orange in bag set?:', 'Orange' in bag

box = {'Red','Purple','Yellow'}
bolength = len(box)
print '\nSet: {}, \tLength: {}'.format(list(box),bolength)
print 'Common to both sets:' , list(bag.intersection(box))
```

**OUPUT:**

> Tuple: ('Kangaroo', 'Leopard', 'Moose'),  Length: 3
>
> Set: ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'],  Length: 4
>
> Is Green In bag Set?: True
>
> Is orange in bag set?: False
>
> Set: ['Purple', 'Red', 'Yellow'],     Length: 3
>
> Common to both sets: ['Yellow', 'Red']

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 the name print is recognized as the print statement, not as a built-in function. You can disable the statement and use the print() function by adding the following future statement at the top of your module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Thus, for example:

```
>>> zoo = ("Kangaroo","Leopard","Moose")
>>> print("Tuple:", zoo, "\tLength:", len(zoo))
('Tuple:', ('Kangaroo', 'Leopard', 'Moose'), '\tLength:', 3)
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("Tuple:", zoo, "\tLength:", len(zoo))
Tuple: ('Kangaroo', 'Leopard', 'Moose')         Length: 3
>>>
```